# Unable to add/checkout/checkin files/folders to ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am getting strange error (see below) when I am trying to add/checkout/checkin a file/folder. I never used to get this error before. The only change is that this is the new UCM Project. Has anyone seen this error?

[image: Error]

How would you troubleshoot that error message.

Here is the text version (for facilitating future text search)

```
CRMAP7018: Unable to create M:\user1_dev_cm_training_view\training\new_folder
CRMAP7026: unknown error.
  reason: write-failed
  resource: null
```

Comment: Go to ClearCase Home Base -> Administration -> ClearCase Doctor and hit "Start Analysis" - this should tell you whether there are any problems with your ClearCase setup.

Comment: I did that. There are no problems detected.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar error message when the CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP environment variable isn't properly set.

It should reference the primary group of the vob you are trying to access. 
(in  CTE - ClearTeam Explorer, `Window -> Preferences -> IBM Rational ClearTeam Explorer -> Groups`)

---

In your case, this is ClearTeam 8.0.0.6, the new name for CCRC, which supports dynamic views, and in an heterogeneous environment (Windows client, Unix server)

The first thing to check are the logs:

- client logs for CTE
- server logs for ClearCase server
- System Event Viewer logs on the client side.

If nothing obvious seems to show up:

- check if there is a process keeping an handle on `M:\user1_dev_cm_training_view\training`
  (one way is simply to reboot and check if the issue persists)
- check if the issue persists with another new dynamic view (and then with another account on another machine)
- Check if a latest patch might resolve the issue ([like a 8.0.0.7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023148#8007))

I don't see any mention of CRMAP7018 or CRMAP7026 on ibm.com.

Comment: That is set correctly. It used to work before. It just started giving this error.

Comment: @clearcase what ClearCase version are you using? CC7.2.x or ClearTeam Explorer CC 8.x? Is your ClearCase server on unix?

Comment: Also one more thing..The old ones still work correctly. The new ones are having this issue.

Comment: CC 8.0.0.6. Yes server is on Unix.

Comment: @clearcase I don't have a definitive answer, but there are other elements to check. See my edited answer.